# Using grep with perl to find files

Tags: regex, perl, grep

I am new to perl, and I am currently stuck on this problem.

1. I have multiple files in a directory
2. I want to check their names, and see if the filename matches a certain keyword (not whole filename).
   So in conclusion, I want to grab the certain files that all have a certain keyword, then process them.

I was trying something like

```
grep -rl "keyword" /.; 
#where does the filenames get stored? let's say in $_?
#foreach valid file, do something
```

from some website I found, but it doesn't seem to work? Help please, Thanks!!

Comment: Grep is a bash command. Do you really want to use Perl? If you just want to search a keyword in a filename, you can go with `find *keyword*`

Comment: if it is a bash problem, you could `find -type f -name 'keyword*.*'|xargs further processing`

Comment: what is a bash command? also, im using this as a parsing script/program, i just needed it to find the files i wanted to continue the parsing.

Comment: @bashophil [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) is also a core Perl function

Comment: @chrsblck but you don't have to call Perl from within a terminal just to use `grep`. @ps_chou `bash` is a shell. Which system are you running on? You can simply search for the filenames in a standard terminal.

Comment: @bashophil No, but if this is just one task in a perl script you do.

Comment: @chrsblck, bashophil misspok slightly. He meant "What you posted is a bash command." That's why it doesn't work in Perl.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
 ls *keyword*
```

If you trying to do this within perl

```
 @files = glob("*keyword*");
 for $file (@files)
 {
   print "$file\n";
 }
```

Note that `grep` in perl is a core function, but it has nothing to do with regular expressions.  It is a more like SQL `where`; it filters an array to a subarray by applying a function (which may or may not be a regex) to each element.

If glob expressions are not good enough, you can do

```
 @files = grep /(fun[kK]y_)keyword?/ glob("*");
```

Comment: ahhh thank you! yeah i am new to perl, so i dont know the difference between grep and glob(which to be honest, i havent learned)

Comment: also, if i know there will only be one file with the keyword in certain folders, can i just do $file = glob("*keyword*"); print $file? and what is the difference betweer glob("keyword") which doesnt work, and glob("*keyword*")?? thx!!

Comment: @ps_chou Use backticks to enter code into comments ``like so``

Comment: You need to use `*` around your keyword if you want to match files like `keyword_1` and `my keyword`. Otherwise, it will only match a file that is exactly `keyword`. I think your comment got garbled, because stack overflow has special formatting characters.

Comment: `$file = glob("*keyword*"); print $file;` i was wondering if this could work? because i used this, which prints the filename once, immediately followed by "use of uninitialized value $file..." how come?

Comment: Try `($file) = glob("*keyword*"); print "$file\n";`

Comment: wow... just adding the brackets fixed it, thanks so much. im sorry to bother you with all these newbie questions, but what was the difference between $file and($file)? and `print "$file\n";` and `print $file, "\n";`

Comment: @ps_chou `print` takes a list of arguments, and the former is a list of one string, the latter two strings. The result is the same, and the strings are printed, separated by whatever is contained in the `$,` variable, described in `perldoc perlvar`. Parentheses normally add list context, which can make the right hand operator return different results, but in this case, I cannot detect any difference in result with or without parentheses. It is probably that `glob` in scalar context iterates over the results instead of returning a list.

Comment: Perl has this pathologic idea that the return value depends on where you assign it. `$a = glob` forces glob to return a scalar, while `@a = glob` forces glob to return a list.  A TLP mentioned, it behaves differently depending on whether it is a scalar or list.  The equivalent of `($file) = glob` is `@a = glob ; $file=$a[0];`

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -E 'say for <*keyword*>'
```